# Node.js Zlib error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, zlib

I have been developing an HTTP server on top of Node.js, While the code is developed I have been experiencing some problems with **content-encoding type gzip**, Whenever I try to Post some JSON with content-encoding gzip I get the following error.

```
Error: unexpected end of file
    at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)
```

I have no other alternative since the client that will be posting to the server will set the content-encoding as gzip

I am using node version 8.8.1, express version 4.16.2 and zlib version 1.0.5. I have the whole setup on CentOS 7.4

What is possibly wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]